# Stay in the same tab after page reload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a webpage consists of tabs by following this tutorial
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

In one of the tabs i have a form to be submitted, once pressing the submit button, the page reloads.

My question is, how do i stay on the same tab that contains the form after page reload. (or is it actually not so appropriate to use the tutorial for complicated contents to begin with?)

Ps: the default opened tab is different from the tab with the form

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You redirect the client server side.

Comment: After submission, redirect back to same tab. For this you need to store somewhere which tab is active like inside a variable or localstorage . I will suggest to store inside a variable .

Comment: use e.preventdefault() t prevent page from reloading after submission. And it would be good if you can provide a working snippet of your code.